# ngFor - assign "shortcut" to variable in iterated complex object

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an ngFor loop in my Angular app, in which I am iterating through an array of complex, deep objects.  There is a variable deep inside these complex objects that needs to regularly be accessed.  Is there a way of creating a "shortcut" variable that would let me access it simply?

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of transactions;let i=index">
  <td>
    <h5 class="text-dark">{{transaction.purchase.subscription.customer.name}}</h5>
    <span *ngIf="transaction.purchase.subscription.customer.is_company" class="text-mute">{{transaction.purchase.subscription.customer.contact_first_name}} {{transaction.purchase.subscription.customer.contact_first_name}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I would like a way of doing something like `let customer=transaction.purchase.subscription.customer` for this loop so I don't have to keep calling the whole thing.

Comment: Add a getter in the Transaction class (assuming there is one), or a method in your component?

Comment: Can you post from where `transactions` is populated? I mean is it static variable of its getting populated from service?

Comment: Don't use a method in component as JB Nizet suggested, it is a bad practice https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some ideas. No one is perfect:

### Custom pipe

Write a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'getCustomer'})
export class GetCustomerPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(transaction: Transaction): Customer {
    return transaction.purchase.subscription.customer;
  }
}
```

And in your component, use it:

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of transactions;let i=index">
  <td>
    <h5 class="text-dark">{{(transaction | getCustomer).name}}</h5>
    <span *ngIf="(transaction | getCustomer).is_company" class="text-mute">{{(transaction | getCustomer).contact_first_name}} {{(transaction | getCustomer).contact_first_name}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Because this pipe is pure, it has performance advantages over a method in the component.

### Unnecessary *ngIf

Add an unnecessary *ngIf in your component, and use is `as` feature

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of transactions;let i=index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="transaction.purchase.subscription.customer as customer">
        <td>
            <h5 class="text-dark">{{customer.name}}</h5>
            <span *ngIf="customer.is_company" class="text-mute">
                {{customer.contact_first_name}} {{customer.contact_first_name}}
            </span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom structural directive `appLet` which lets you define a variable.

```
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

interface LetContext<T> {
    appLet: T;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLet]'
})
export class LetDirective<T> {

  private _context: LetContext<T> = { appLet: null };

  @Input()
    set appLet(value: T) {
        this._context.appLet = value;
    }

  constructor(_viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, _templateRef: TemplateRef<LetContext<T>>) {
    _viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef, this._context);
  }
}
```

And use it like this in your template

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of transactions;let i=index">
  <td *appLet="transaction.purchase.subscription.customer as customer">
    <h5 class="text-dark">{{customer.name}}</h5>
    <span *ngIf="customer.is_company" class="text-mute">{{customer.contact_first_name}} {{customer.contact_first_name}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```